# Replacing Switches with Potentiometer

Tags: audio, potentiometer

I'm planning on buying [this audio amplifier](http://www.ebay.com/itm/181406329936) for a project:
[image]

Everything about it is great, except for the fact that volume is controlled by two tact switches for volume up and down. I want to replace it with a wheel potentiometer, so I found [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/381862903174).

Can this actually be done, and if so, how?

Comment: No, not with a wheel pot. (Unless you add a small micro, anyway.) You should by one that accepts a pot, instead. Or else plan on some struggles. (some pain with a rotary encoder comes to mind, or finding a dual incremental rotary encoder that generates pulses on one switch when rotated clockwise and another switch when rotated counter-clockwise.)

Comment: @jonk, quadrature encoder to discrete up/down is a doddle, do it with a 74HCT00 and an R-C. Two BAT54 for TTL-to-switch conversion and go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do what you want would be to set the amplifier itself to the maximum gain that you want to use, and then use the potentiometer in the usual way to vary the level of the analog signal that you send to it.

Comment: So you're saying I should set the volume with the tact switches to the highest I want it to go, then add a pot separately to adjust that signal?

Answer (score 1):

You can not plug directly the wheel potentiometer to the chip. You have to add a microcontroller that will emit a pulse every X rotation to the chip.

If you don't want to use a µC, you can use an encoder : the encoder will generate a pulse every X rotation on one pin. I think will fit your need.

http://www.ebay.com/itm/3Pcs-6mm-D-Shaft-18-Position-360-Degree-Rotary-Encoder-w-Push-Button-LW-/171816111876